# ASP.NET Core on Ubuntu

Tags: asp.net, ubuntu, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm trying to set up a .NET environment on Ubuntu 16.04. I followed the instruction on https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#ubuntu

When I run the second command:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver apt-mo.trafficmanager.net --recv-keys 417A0893
```

I'm getting the following errors:

```
Executing: /tmp/tmp.7IpPJJZVuc/gpg.1.sh --keyserver
apt-mo.trafficmanager.net
--recv-keys
417A0893
gpg: requesting key 417A0893 from hkp server apt-mo.trafficmanager.net
gpg: keyserver timed out
gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error
```

I disabled the OS fire wall using:

```
sudo ufw disable
```

And restarted my system. But still the same result.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution here: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/2189

> Since keyservers are synchronizing keys you can actually use any other keyserver like the Ubuntu one for getting the MS key:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 417A0893
```